# Count of 2 distinct columns

Tags: oracle

How can I get the count of 2 columns such that there are distinct combinations of two columns?

```
Select count(distinct cola, colb)
```

Comment: Please post the desired resultset.

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT a, b
        FROM    mytable
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT COLA, COLB
      FROM YOUR_TABLE
    )
```

Comment: He needs the count of each column.

Comment: @James: OP says he wants the count of distinct combinations of both COlumns, for which I will include the COUNT.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT COLA || COLB)
FROM THE_TABLE
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c287e/2

Comment: That won't work all that well if the columns are not strings in the first place.  It will also miscount things if there is a row with ColA = "abc" and ColB = "def" and another row with ColA = "ab" and ColB = "cdef"; they will be counted as 1 whereas they should be counted as 2.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT (select count(cola) from ...), (select count(colb) from ...) from ...

You may want to look at this:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/Aggregate-Functions/COUNTcolumnandCOUNTcountthenumberofrowspassedintothefunction.htm

You can put `Distinct` in the subqueries, if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle DB, you can concat the columns and then count on that concatenated String like below:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT concat(ColumnA, ColumnB)) FROM TableX;
```

In MySql, you can just add the columns as parameters in count method.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT ColumnA, ColumnB) FROM TableX;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT a, b
        FROM    mytable
        ) As Temp
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Generally speaking, if you're going to provide a new answer to an older question such as this, you should ensure that your answer is distinctly different from, or better than, the existing answers.  As it stands, your answer is identical to one previous answer (give or take spacing), and substantially equivalent to another (`COUNT(1)` vs `COUNT(*)`).  Consequently, you're unlikely to reap many rewards for repeating what others have already said.