# JPA and Oracle DB: Distinct query with pagination leads to Error: ORA-00909: Invalid amount of arguments

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Im running a spring backend with an oracle database.
I use the specification API to perform queries:

```java
@Slf4j
public class ContentSpecification implements Specification<Content> {

  private final transient ContentFilter filter;

  public ContentSpecification(final ContentFilter filter) {
    this.filter = filter;
  }

  @Override
  public Predicate toPredicate(
      @NonNull final Root<Content> root,
      @NonNull final CriteriaQuery<?> query,
      @NonNull final CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    final List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    if (!isEmpty(filter.getTerm())) {
      // ... not relevant

      predicates.add(builder.or(title, subtitle, body, keywords));
    }
    
    query.distinct(true);

    return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
  }
}
```

```java
  public PagedModel<ContentModel> getContent(
      final String term,
      final Integer page,
      final Integer size) {

    final int pageSize = size == 0 ? MAX_VALUE : size;

    return pagedAssembler
        .toModel(
            repository.findAll(
                new ContentSpecification(
                    new ContentFilter(term)),
                PageRequest.of(page, pageSize)),
            contentAssembler);
  }
```

This is working perfectly with H2 and MySQL Database.
But as soon as im using an Oracle database it wont work:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    initialization-mode: never
    url: <url>
    username: <user>
    password: <pw>
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        current_session_context_class: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
    show-sql: true
```

The console output im getting is the following:

```
2021-12-07 15:24:22.487  INFO [my-service,4d641a9f03674994,4d641a9f03674994,false] 14244 --- [nio-8082-exec-7] d.b.b.p.p.content.ContentController      : get content: null, null, null, 0, 5
Hibernate: 
    select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            distinct content0_.id as id2_3_,
            content0_.version as version3_3_,
            content0_.status as status9_3_,
            content0_.status_date as status_date10_3_,
            content0_.subtitle as subtitle11_3_,
            content0_.title as title12_3_,
        from
            content content0_ 
        where
            content0_.status=? ) 
    where
        rownum <= ?
Hibernate: 
    select
        distinct count(distinct content0_.id,
        content0_.version) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        content content0_ 
    where
        content0_.status=?
2021-12-07 15:24:22.508  WARN [my-service,4d641a9f03674994,4d641a9f03674994,false] 14244 --- [nio-8082-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 909, SQLState: 42000
2021-12-07 15:24:22.508 ERROR [my-service,4d641a9f03674994,4d641a9f03674994,false] 14244 --- [nio-8082-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00909: Invalid amount of arguments
2021-12-07 15:24:22.514 ERROR [my-service,4d641a9f03674994,4d641a9f03674994,false] 14244 --- [nio-8082-exec-7] d.b.b.p.p.ApplicationExceptionHandler    : runtime exception: 

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    ... 111 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00909: Ungültige Anzahl von Argumenten
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:461) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1104) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:655) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:270) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:91) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:807) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:983) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3666) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1426) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3713) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1167) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.2.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.12.Final.jar:5.4.12.Final]
    ... 148 common frames omitted
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00909: Ungültige Anzahl von Argumenten

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:513) ~[ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar:19.3.0.0.0]
    ... 165 common frames omitted
```

As soon as I remove either the `distinct` or the `pagination` it will also work with the oracle db.

Is there a solution for oracle to get the distinct running together with the pagination?

**EDIT**

So it seems like oracle fails with the count query.
Just for comparison, with H2 the following sql is
getting generated:

```sql
Hibernate: 
    select
        distinct content0_.id as id2_3_,
        content0_.version as version3_3_,
        content0_.status as status9_3_,
        content0_.status_date as status_10_3_,
        content0_.subtitle as subtitl11_3_,
        content0_.title as title12_3_,
    from
        content content0_ 
    where
        content0_.status=? limit ?
Hibernate: 
    select
        distinct count(distinct (content0_.id,
        content0_.version)) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        content content0_ 
    where
        content0_.status=?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error `ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments` is the statement providing the count of the rows

```
select
        distinct count(distinct content0_.id,
        content0_.version) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        content content0_
...
```

This construction `COUNT(DISTINCT expr,[expr...])` maight be allowed in [MySQL](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php)

but is *illegal* in Oracle.

As your *dialect* is `Oracle12cDialect` I'd suspect a *problem* in the implementation of this dialect in case of *more than one identifying columns in the entity*. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5677665/4808122) for correct SQL  solutions.

Also note that the *first* `DISTINCT` in this query is possible, but completely *irrelevant* as a query with `count` will produce only *one row*-

Having said that you should IMO make some effort in your data model that will make the usage of `distinct` *not necessary*.  IMHO the *right* approach.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. The library which implements hibernate for oracle is generating the sql... but it is generating illegal sql....

Answer (score 0):

Actually the failing query:

> ````
>     select
>         distinct count(distinct (content0_.id,
>         content0_.version)) as col_0_0_ 
>     from
>         content content0_ 
>     where
>         content0_.status=? ```
> ````

is a query which spring-data issues to get the total amount of records available (please check: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository#executeCountQuery - actually, it would worth to provide the full stacktrace). And it seems that your Content entity has composite PK, i.e. (id, version) (again, no entity definition provided), but HBN experiences some difficulties with such queries: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11042